# Add elements to two arrays based on condition

Tags: c, arrays

There is an array x and I want to put its elements in arrays y and z based of some if condition.

```
    int x[10],y[5],z[5];
    for(for x array)
      if(some condition)
         {
             //put in y
        }
       else   {
             //put in z
             }
```

What I am not able to figure out is how to keep track of indexes in array y and z while assigning the elements. Any help/suggestion is appreciated. Thnak you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For statically defined arrays;

```
int x[10],y[5],z[5];
for(for x array)
  if(some condition)
  {
         //yindex is the index of the y array where you are going to assign the value
         if(yindex < sizeof(y) / sizeof(y[0]))
         {
            y[yindex] = value;
         }
  }
```

Comment: what will be the initial value of yindex ?  0?

Comment: And what you think yourself: 1. `0`, 2. `3`, 3. `5`, 4. `8`

Comment: yindex is just the number, it can be variable or a result of some expression. I do not know the logic of your program

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will be 0, since I will assigning from the start of array.

Comment: Thanks! for the answer though.

Comment: @Abhishek Thakur it always works for the one dimentional arrays with known size as this expression is evaluated during **compilation** not the runtime,. Post your **real** code and I will tell you what is wrong

Comment: I figured that one out. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with any arrays, C doesn't provide any *bounds checking*, that responsibility is left solely to you as the C-programmer. Attempting to access an element outside the defined array bounds invokes *Undefined Behavior*.

To prevent straying off into undefined behavior, always keep track to the current array index (when filling) and test against a *Max* array index. While you can use `sizeof array / sizeof *array` be aware that is only valid *within the scope where the array was declared*. Once the array is passed as a parameter to a function, the first level of indirection is *converted to a pointer* and `sizeof` thereafter will return `sizeof (a pointer)` not the array size.

Don't use *magic numbers* in your code. If you need constants in your code, define them at the top of your code, either with, e.g. `#define XMAX 10`, or use an `enum` to declare them. That way, if you ever need to change the bounds (or whatever the constant is used for), you have a single location at the top, and you don't have to go picking though every loop or conditional you hardcoded some *magic number* in.

A quick example in your case separating the odd/even numbers in `x` into `y` & `z` could be done by:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum { YZMAX = 5, XMAX = 10 };

int main (void) {

    int x[XMAX]  = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
        y[YZMAX] = {0},
        z[YZMAX] = {0};
    size_t yndx = 0, zndx = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < XMAX; i++)
        if (yndx < YZMAX && (x[i] & 1) == 0) {
            y[yndx++] = x[i];
        }
        else if (zndx < YZMAX) {
            z[zndx++] = x[i];
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < YZMAX; i++)
        printf (" y[%d] : %d        z[%d] : %d\n", i, y[i], i, z[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/xyzindex
 y[0] : 0        z[0] : 1
 y[1] : 2        z[1] : 3
 y[2] : 4        z[2] : 5
 y[3] : 6        z[3] : 7
 y[4] : 8        z[4] : 9
```

---

**Reading a 2D Array from Command Line Arguments**

Whether you are reading a 1D array or 2D array, the process is the same. The only thing that changes is keeping up with one additional index. In your comment, you provide the additional twist of having multiple integers contained within a single command-line argument string. While it may appear confusing at first, if you think about it, it is no different than reading multiple integers from a single line of text in a file.

While you suggest two arguments of `"2 4"` and `"3 5"`, there is no reason to worry about how many integers are in each argument. Handling `"2 4 3"` and `"5"` would work the same (or `"2 4 3 5"` or `2 4 3 5` for that matter)

**note:** you will generally not want to provide array values as *command-line* arguments (you can, but...) you generally want to read values from a file (or `stdin` - a file as well). Command line arguments are generally used to influence code behavior (e.g., `--help`, etc..) or provide filenames from which values can be read rather than providing the values themselves. It's up to you. (for simple test code it is fine to use the arguments for anything you need)

The key is just to read each integer (regardless of which argument it comes from) update your row/column indexes, and take whatever additional steps are required before returning to read the next integer. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW 2
#define COL 2
#define BASE 10

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) {         /* validate at least one argument string given */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n"
                        "usage: %s [followed by %d integers]\n",
                        argv[0], ROW + COL);
        return 1;
    }

    int arr[ROW][COL] = {{0}},      /* array */
        row = 0, col = 0,           /* row / col indexes */
        ndx = 1;                    /* argument index */

    /* loop over each argument until array filled. 
     * you don't know how many integers could be
     * in each argument., e.g. ("2 4" and "3 5")
     */
    while (ndx < argc) {
        char *p = argv[ndx];            /* pointer to current argument */
        int offset = 0, tmp;

        /* convert each int in argument and get offset in arg for next */
        while (sscanf (p, "%d%n", &tmp, &offset) == 1) 
        {
            arr[row][col++] = tmp;      /* assign value to element */

            if (col == COL)             /* test if column full */
                row++, col = 0;         /* increment row, zero column */

            if (row == ROW)             /* test if array full */
                goto done;              /* goto required to break 2 loops */

            p += offset;                /* increment p by offset */
        }
        ndx++;                          /* process next argument */
    }
    done:;

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {                     /* for each row */
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)                   /* for each col */
            printf (" %2d", arr[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_2d_args "2 4" "3 5"
  2  4
  3  5

$ ./bin/array_2d_args "2 4 3" "5"
  2  4
  3  5

$ ./bin/array_2d_args "2 4 3 5"
  2  4
  3  5

$ ./bin/array_2d_args 2 4 3 5
  2  4
  3  5
```

Reading from a file would work the same way. Instead of looping over arguments, you would simply loop over lines read with `fgets` processing the integers in each line of text read with `sscanf` or handling both the read and conversion of single values with `fscanf`.

**note**: there are advantages in using `strtol` for the conversion to integer rather than `sscanf`, as it provides a great deal more error handling information, but also requires a bit of additional code to preform the error checking.

---

**Reading values from a file or `stdin`**

As noted above, in many cases it is actually easier to read directly from a file rather than using command-line arguments. Here is a short example. In this case rather than reading an integer then and handling the indexes, we use two loops to limit the number of integers read to the number of times the loops execute. Either way is fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ROW 2
#define COL 2

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int arr[ROW][COL] = {{0}};

    /* open filename given by argv[1] (or use stdin as default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)                       /* for each row */
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)                   /* for each col */
            if (fscanf (fp, "%d", &arr[i][j]) != 1) {   /* read element */
                /* handle error */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input arr[%d][%d].\n", i, j);
                return 1;
            }

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);     /* close file if not stdin */

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {                     /* for each row */
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++)                   /* for each col */
            printf (" %2d", arr[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/2x2.txt
2 4
3 5
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/array_2d_file <dat/2x2.txt
  2  4
  3  5
```

**note:** there is no need that the input be in rows or columns since you are reading a single integer at a time with `fscanf` -- and -- the `"%d"` *format specifier* will skip all leading whitespace (including the `'\n'`) before reading the next number. So the input can be a on a single line or on 4-lines, e.g.

All on one line:

```
$ echo "2 4 3 5"
2 4 3 5

$ echo "2 4 3 5" | ./bin/array_2d_file
  2  4
  3  5
```

or mixed on multiple lines

```
$ printf "2\n4\n3\n\n5\n"
2
4
3

5

$ printf "2\n4\n3\n\n5\n" | ./bin/array_2d_file
  2  4
  3  5
```

or

```
$ printf "2\n4 3\n\n5\n"
2
4 3

5

$ printf "2\n4 3\n\n5\n" | ./bin/array_2d_file
  2  4
  3  5
```

Look things over in all answers and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Thank you for all of your suggestions. I will keep them in mind.

Comment: Sure, glad to help. You will enjoy C. It is a fantastic language. Best advice anyone can give to new C programmers is just to *slow down*, there is a lot there, but take your time and enjoy the learning process. C gives you hardware level access, but to do so places a lot of responsibility on you to do things right. No guessing, when you have a question, look it up. If you still have questions, drop back by and everyone is glad to help.

Comment: Also there is one more question. How can i take input to 2-d array with 2 rows and 2 column such that in command line I can Give input as (in first row) 2  4 (in next row) 3  5. Notice that there is space between both numbers.

Comment: No problem, I'll add another short example.

Comment: @AbhishekThakur - I added two different examples for you. One using the *command-line* arguments as your propose, and a second example reading the values from a file rather than as command line arguments.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer. It might take me a while to understand all this stuff. But I will try my best. I'm not so good with C (I miss PYTHON).

Comment: The key to C is to just *slow down*... There is a lot to understand when you are working at the hardware level with a language that places the responsibility on you to do the right thing. Just take each line of code statement-by-statement and lookup any function you don't know with `man function_name` in Linux (or google "man function_name"). Check a reference/tutorial for any language issue, pointer issue, that is new to you. Don't expect to learn it all in one day, or month, or year. How do you eat a Whale? (*one bite at a time...*)

Comment: Yeah that's for sure. I got a new problem today. How can I use regular expressions for input if at all. Like I want user to enter "[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}" but it seems like it don't work with scanf(). So all i can do is compare ASCII value of each element separately. Is that so?

Comment: C has a whole regex set of functions for creating patterns that you can then apply. They are provided in the `regex.h` header file. Regexs are stored in `regex_t` variable types, and  `regcomp` is used to compile the `regex` and then the `regex` can use the function `regexec` to execute it. Take a look at [**Roman Numeral Regexes**](https://ideone.com/xxTulr). It gives basic function usage you can adapt to your problem. Another tip is to see [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... really, it works.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Blog post is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

you can give like that condition if you will initialize at least one array (y or z) with 0, maybe it will be helpful for you. Example:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //put values in x array otherwise it will take by default garbage value.
    int i, j, k, x[10], y[5]={0}, z[5]; 
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&x[i]); //for console input.
    }
    for(i=0, j=0, k=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if(y[j]==0 && j<5)  //if(y[j]==0)
        {
            //put in y
            y[j]=x[i];
            printf("%d ",y[j]);
            j++;
        } else {
            //put in z
            z[k]=x[i];
            printf("%d ",z[k]);
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

when you assign size only like `x[10]` without assigning any elements in C then it will store garbage values in array so if you want to store one array to another array then have to give condition for if() whatever you want to do.

Comment: Very poor solution as zero is the valid value. It is not the same as NULL pointer which can be used to indicate something (for example last node in the list). NULL is guaranteed to be invalid on any machine - zero is always valid

Comment: @PeterJ sir we use  **sizeof(y) / sizeof(y[0]**  for dynamic programing it's good but we are using simple thing and if  we have give size of array then we can take size directly, that's why I given direct learning based solution and also we can use **sizeof(y) / sizeof(y[0]**  it's good practice Thank you.

Comment: I do not understand. What is **dynamic programming**?